# What does the word נחירה mean

Tags: hebrew, slaughter-shochet-shecht

In Modern Hebrew it means "snort", but what about in Classical Hebrew?

I have found this word in Simla Hadosho 1:21. This states that if you want to feed your animals meat but you do not know the laws of shechita or have access to a shochet, then you can either do נחר or rip out the simanim (kone and vaishet)

What does נחר mean in this case? How about in other places?

Thank you
[image]
[image]

Comment: @shalom It says ינחרה on that page (4th line, second image).

Comment: נחירה is what you do to an Am HaAretz on Yom Kippur that falls on Shabbat (Pesachim 49b)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the sense contextually is that he tears it from its nostrils to its chest (see [Rashi Chullin 17a s.v. *v'hanocher*](http://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.17a.21?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all) [hattip @wfb]) or [stabs](http://www.biu.ac.il/JH/Parasha/reeh/gol.html) it (see e.g. *Krithuth* 5:1) or [strangles](http://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.85b.43?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all) it in such a manner that it is clearly not a kosher *shechita*. See e.g. [this Wiktionary entry](https://he.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%94#.D7.A0.D6.B0.D7.97.D6.B4.D7.99.D7.A8.D6.B8.D7.94_.D7.91). See also [Chullin 17a](http://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.17a.5?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all).

Comment: Does not rashi in your link explain it as choking?

Comment: He does. I was about to edit that in.

Comment: I believe Rashi in one place defines it as cutting the simanim lengthwise

Comment: I was probably thinking of this Rashi (on 17a) ולשון נחירה שקורעה לאורכה מנחיריה ועד החזה

Answer (score 3):

It appears a lot in mishnayoss.

E.G. Bava Kama (7,5)
הַנּוֹחֵר, וְהַמְעַקֵּר, מְשַׁלֵּם תַּשְׁלוּמֵי כֶפֶל וְאֵינוֹ מְשַׁלֵּם תַּשְׁלוּמֵי אַרְבָּעָה וַחֲמִשָּׁה
The noher ... do not be considered as shohet, and so do not pay X4 or X5

The Bartenura wrote:
הַנּוֹחֵר. קוֹרְעוֹ מִנְּחִירָיו עַד לִבּוֹ
He tore from the nostrils to the heart

This also appears in Masechess Chulin for Kissui Hadam.
This action does not cause the effective and immediate death of the animal, and doesn't cause the statutory death (as shehita does) in matters of Halocho.

I hope that this will help a little bit.

And there is a discussion in chapter 5 of Kretot about the blood that exits from this action, whether this is *blood of death*.